# Is it possible to view py3Dmol or nglview in Pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

Most people seem to use Jupyter Notebook to display nglview and py3dmol models because nglview is a IPython/Jupyter widget.

I am wondering how to go about viewing these biomolecules within my Pycharm IDE, in the same way matplotlib will allow for plotting windows in both applications.

Is this a feature of Pycharm Pro?

Comment: PyCharm Pro allows for the use of Jupyter Notebooks. See [this support article](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/jupyter-notebook-support.html), which also states that "Jupyter Notebook Support [is] available only in PyCharm Professional".

Answer (score 1):

Yes but I think it's only available in PyCharm Professional Edition.

It supports integration with `Jupyter Notebook` and `JupyterLab`, also enables you to visualize widgets like `nglview` and `py3dmol`  within the IDE. But you will also need to have a compatible web browser installed to display the widgets.

If you are using PyCharm Community Edition you can still use `nglview` and `py3dmol`, but you just won't be able to display the widgets within the IDE.

**Update:**

I misunderstood the question. Unfortunately, as I know it is not currently possible to display `nglview` or `py3dmol` widgets directly within the PyCharm IDE window. Because the widgets are rely on `JavaScript` to render the 3D molecule, and PyCharm  does not provide a built-in `JavaScript` runtime.

Comment: It doesn't show the widget in PyCharm professional edition 2023.1. Do you know if it requires additional settings or Jupyter magic commands to show properly?

Comment: Did  you run the ```nglview``` and ```py3dmol``` in code cell?

Comment: Yes, I did. My code shows the widget if I run it in a browser but not in Pycharm. In Pycharm, it throws an error 'Jupyter Javascript: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'widget_manager')'

Comment: Oh I misunderstood your meaning. Unfortunately, as I know it is not currently possible to display ```nglview``` or ```py3dmol``` widgets directly within the PyCharm IDE window. Because the widgets are rely on ```JavaScript``` to render the 3D molecule, and PyCharm  does not provide a built-in ```JavaScript``` runtime.